# How to transfer binary file into rdd in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to load seg-Y type files into spark, and transfer them into rdd for mapreduce operation. 
But I failed to transfer them into rdd. Does anyone who can offer help?

Answer (score 2):

You could use binaryRecords() pySpark call to convert binary file's content into an RDD

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.binaryRecords

> binaryRecords(path, recordLength)
>
> Load data from a
> flat binary file, assuming each record is a set of numbers with the
> specified numerical format (see ByteBuffer), and the number of bytes
> per record is constant.
>
> Parameters:    path – Directory to the input data files recordLength –
> The length at which to split the records

Then you could map() that RDD into a structure by using, for example, struct.unpack()

https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

We use this approach to ingest propitiatory fixed-width records binary files. There is a bit of Python code that generates Format string (1st argument to `struct.unpack`), but if your files layout is static, it's fairly simple to do manually one time.

Similarly is possible to do using pure Scala:

[http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@binaryRecords(path:String,recordLength:Int,conf:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Byte]]](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@binaryRecords(path:String,recordLength:Int,conf:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BArray%5BByte%5D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

You've not really given much detail, but you can start with using the SparkContextbinaryFiles() API

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext