# Scala and Spark : how to go through an image?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some binary files that are images and I would want to go through themselves, distributing the pixels : each node of my cluster must get the RGB of a different group of pixel(s) than another node's ones, and store these RGB into a Scala collection.

I am using `SparkContext::binaryFiles` but I don't know how to make Apache Spark "able to understand" that I am using an Image, that I would want to go through its pixels using distribution, and that I would want to get the RGB values. **Could you help me to do that please ?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spark 2.3 added support for parsing images. You can read images and get meta data and image data like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.image.ImageSchema._
import java.nio.file.Paths

val images = readImages("path/to/images")

images.foreach { rrow =>
  val row = rrow.getAs[Row](0)
  val filename = Paths.get(getOrigin(row)).getFileName().toString()
  val imageData = getData(row)
  val height = getHeight(row)
  val width = getWidth(row)

  println(s"${height}x${width}")
}
```

You can find some more information [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2018/03/05/image-data-support-in-apache-spark/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the binary files, you just need to convert them into a matrix of integers(which are the RGB values). Read how to convert Images to Array of RGB in scala here :

http://otfried.org/scala/image.html

Here is an example done in Python :

[Spark using PySpark read images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138129/spark-using-pyspark-read-images)

Comment: But this conversion won't be distributed unfortunately

Comment: You can use a row matrix to store these values.(which is distributed by default).

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-data-types.html

Comment: Then, the operations I will do on its stored values will be distributed. But the conversion itself still won't (conversion = the image crossing pixel by pixel to store their RGB in that row matrix)

Comment: you can convert binary files into RDD's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602489/how-to-transfer-binary-file-into-rdd-in-spark. This way they're now distributed, and convert them into RGB in whichever node they're found.

Comment: Hey, in this line : `>>> image_to_array = lambda rawdata: np.asarray(Image.open(StringIO(rawdata)))`, the image seems to be used to create the array only by the driver, and not distributed no ?

Comment: Yes, but your binary files will be.. which will make the pixels distributed by default.. and then the array will be created in the driver for each node.

Comment: Mmmh. Tell me if I'm wrong but in the Python example you gave me, the conversion is indeed distributed (`binaryFiles(...)` + `.values().map(...)`). But the reading access to the image is only done by the driver : `np.asarray(...)`. Thus, is it impossible to distribute absolutely everything ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I couldn't find documentation for where reading is distributed, I guess unless and until Spark allows you to do this conversion or supports it for items in RDD(which I couldn't find information on), at this time it might be impossible to distrubte everything. However, this could be useful to you : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-guide.html. If you have time, please read through it, you might find what you need. (I personally haven't read the documentation completely.)