# read and write images in hdfs through spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

Hi I am trying to read a images file from the local file system and store it in HDFS file system through spark and scala.

Here is mycode.

```
val streams = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("file:///home/jeffi/input/Images_Test/")
val op = streams.toDF()  //op: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: string]
op.printSchema() //root |-- _1: string (nullable = true) |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to write the op dataframe in to HDFS, Then I got the following exception

```
 op.write.text("/home/cisadmin/image_op")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source supports only a single column, and you have 2 columns.;
```

I tried with various types in write method like op.write,op.write.wholeTextFiles("")

Nothing works for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you reading image files with text apis ? look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343919/scala-and-spark-how-to-go-through-an-image

Comment: I tried with binary file option also. Nothing works

Comment: may be https://github.com/Microsoft/spark-images/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/image/ImageSchema.scala will help you

Comment: I followed the above link only

Comment: follow them and try it and if they don't work then update the question. we shall help you

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error, If you check `text` method it says,

> Saves the content of the [[DataFrame]] in a text file at the specified
>   path. 
>   The DataFrame must have only one column that is of string type.
>   Each row becomes a new line in the output file.

But in your case `op` has two columns, so either you can save your file as csv or convert it to `RDD` then save it as a text file.

But as Ramesh Maharjan mentioned you should not use text APIs for reading image files.

Comment: Got it. I am modifying my code. let you know If I face any issues